# How to call this Apex Action class in test class?

Tags: apex

I have the following class which is an Apex Action called from a flow.  Others have kindly helped me have this working for bulkification already.

It takes an input ID for a lead and returns a deduplicated list of tasks (de-duped by subject).  Even before de-duplication its starting set must contain certain things within the subject (so we don't further process unnecessarily).

I am struggling to understand how to call this class in a Test class.  Below is also the starter for my test class.  Could someone assist me with calling the final class, passing in my test data?  Once I have that piece I should be Ok to system.assert the responses etc.

Thanks in advance!

Class:

```
public class tasksListAction {
    //this invocable method takes a single task id from Flow from a record variable
    //and returns a list of tasks.
    //the list of lists is stored as a collection variable in the Flow.
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'SendTasksGetTasks'
        description = 'returns tasks for this lead.')

    //this method returns a List of Lists of Tasks to the flow and receives a List of Ids
    public static List < List < Task >> getLeadIds(List < ID > ids) {

        //Store in a list the id, subject and Who ID of tasks linked to our target lead.  
        //Tasks must start 'opened' and contain a '-'
        List < Task > taskis = [SELECT id, subject, whoid
            FROM TASK
            WHERE whoid in: ids
            AND Subject LIKE 'Opened%'
            AND Subject LIKE '%-%'
            ORDER BY ID
        ];


        //declare a new list of lists of tasks
        List < List < Task >> itemListList = new List < List < Task >> ();

        //Store results by Lead Id and by unique Subject
        //Lead Id ==> Unique Subject ==> List of Tasks
        //If lead Id exists in Map, add additional returned tasks by subject
        Map < String, Map < String, List < Task >>> mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId = new Map < String, Map < String, List < Task >>> ();
        for (Task task: taskis) {
            if (mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(task.WhoId) != null) {
                Map < String, List < Task >> additionalTasksBySubject = mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(task.WhoId);
                List < Task > additionalTask = new List < Task > {
                    task
                };
                additionalTasksBySubject.put(task.Subject, additionalTask);
                mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.put(task.WhoId, additionalTasksBySubject);
            } else {
                Map < String, List < Task >> tasksBySubject = new Map < String, List < Task >> {
                    task.Subject => new List < Task > {
                        task
                    }
                };
                mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.put(task.WhoId, tasksBySubject);
            }
        }

        //Buld return output for flow - need a List<Task> for each record in bulk
        for (String leadId: ids) {
            //If no records found for Lead Id, return an empty list
            //Otherwise, get returned Task records by Lead + unique subjects
            if (mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(leadId) != null) {
                List < Task > allUniqueSubjectTasks = new List < Task > ();
                Map < String, List < Task >> tasksBySubject = mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(leadId);
                //Combine all unique subject task results for one Lead into one list to return one list per Lead Id in the method
                for (List < Task > subjectTasks: tasksBySubject.values()) {
                    allUniqueSubjectTasks.addAll(subjectTasks);
                }
                itemListList.add(allUniqueSubjectTasks);
            } else {
                itemListList.add(new List < Task > ());
            }
        }
        return itemListList;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
public class TesttasksListAction {
    testmethod static void testTesttasksListAction() {


        // Create test data
        Lead l = new Lead(company = 'Salesforce', LastName = 'Test Task Action', Status = 'Interested');
        insert l;
        Task T = new Task(subject = 'Opened marketing message 1 - 01 November 2022', WhoID = l.Id);
        Task TT = new Task(subject = 'Opened marketing message 1 - 01 November 2022', WhoID = l.Id);
        Task TTT = new Task(subject = 'Opened marketing message 2 - 05 November 2022', WhoID = l.Id);
        Task TTTT = new Task(subject = 'I should not be included at all', WhoID = l.Id);
        insert new List < Task > {
            T,
            TT,
            TTT,
            TTTT
        };

        // based on above 4 messages, 3 should be processed initially, and the deduplicated set of tasks returned should only be T and TTT
        //starting the test

        Test.startTest();

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just call `tasksListAction.getLeadIds` passing in an array of relevant IDs. From the apex unit test perspective there's nothing special about this method. You just need to call it.

Comment: Thanks... yeah I was just being a bit dense!  It was passing in the list of list <ID> where I was throwing myself and thought it was something deeper than my being a donut!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here's how I handled it:

```
@isTest
public class TesttasksListAction{
testmethod static void testTesttasksListAction(){

    
     // Create test data
        Lead l = new Lead(company = 'Salesforce', LastName='Test Task Action', Status = 'Interested');
        insert l;
        Task T = new Task(subject = 'Opened marketing message 1 - 01 November 2022', WhoID = l.Id);
        Task TT = new Task(subject = 'Opened marketing message 1 - 01 November 2022', WhoID = l.Id);
        Task TTT = new Task(subject = 'Opened marketing message 2 - 05 November 2022', WhoID = l.Id);
        Task TTTT = new Task(subject = 'I should not be included at all', WhoID = l.Id);
        insert new List<Task>{T, TT, TTT, TTTT};
        
      // based on above 4 messages, 3 should be processed initially, and the deduplicated set of tasks returned should only be T and TTT
     //starting the test

    Test.startTest();
    list<list<task>> ret_tasks_list = tasksListAction.getLeadIds(new List<ID> {l.id});
    system.assert(ret_tasks_list != null);    
    list<task> ret_tasks = new List<task>();
    ret_tasks = ret_tasks_list[0];
    System.assertEquals(2,ret_tasks.size()); 
    System.assertEquals('Opened marketing message 1 - 01 November 2022',ret_tasks[0].subject);      
    System.assertEquals('Opened marketing message 2 - 05 November 2022',ret_tasks[1].subject);                          
    Test.stopTest();
   
    }

}
```